# list through file using a while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I cannot get this to work properly, I need the program to list through the records within the file, if $records[$row][2]is the same as the previous, it should repeat class 'field' with a new $records[$row][2], otherwise it should start a new #row.  Please help!

```
if (($handle = fopen('upload/ATLANTA.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {


    $prevRow2 = '';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        $records[] = $data;

        echo 'Previous'. $prevRow2;
        echo "<div id=\"row\"><div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>";

        if ($records[$row][2] == $prevRow2) {

            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($c != 1) {  
                echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $data[$c] . "</div>";
                }   
            }
            $prevRow2 = $records[$row][2];
            $row++;
        }
        else {
            echo "<div id=\"row\"><div id=\"num\">" .$row. "</div>";
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($c != 1) {  
                echo "<div class=\"field\">" . $data[$c] . "</div>";
                }   
            }
            $prevRow2 = $records[$row][2];
            $row++;
            echo "</div>";
        }




    echo "</div>";
}
fclose($handle);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you seem to assume that your CSV file is ordered by the column you want to group on. If this is not the case, then you should first read the file, sort it, and then print it. If your CSV file is not too big for the memory of your server, this should work.

Also, your code has repetitions and store the entire file into an array (actually, just like I suggested above, but I don't know if it is intentional). try something like this:

This is my demo.csv:

```
"Banana", "yellow"
"Lemon", "yellow"
"Orange", "orange"
"Strawberry", "red"
"Tomato", "red"
```

This is the PHP to loop through it and list it by color:

```
<?php

if (($handle = fopen('demo.csv', "r"))) {
    $prev = false;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) {
        if ($prev !== $data[1]) {
            $prev = $data[1];
            echo '<p><b>' . $prev . '</b></p>';
        }
        echo $data[0] . '<br>';
    }
}
fclose($handle);

?>
```

This is the output in HTML (I added some linebreaks for proper display here)

```
<p><b>yellow</b></p>
Banana<br>
Lemon<br>
<p><b>orange</b></p>
Orange<br>
<p><b>red</b></p>
Strawberry<br>
Tomato<br>
```

(If the CSV was not grouped by color, you'd need a different approach.)

Comment: My CSV is grouped.  This is what I get from using your code:
"yellow"
Banana

"yellow"
Lemon

"orange"
Orange

"red"
Strawberry

"red"
Tomato

While I need it to look like this: Whenever the $data[1] is the same as the previous, I need that record grouped together with the one before it. 

Banana
    "yellow"
    Lemon "yellow"

Orange  "orange"
Strawberry "red"
      Tomato  "red"

Comment: I've modified the code to try to do this, but its still not working. Its never going into the inner loop.
Here's the code:
if (($handle = fopen('demo.csv', "r"))) {
    $prev = false;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))) {
    print 'Comparing' . $prev . 'to' .  $data[1];
   if ($data[1] == $prev) {
 print 'Previous is the same<br/>';
 print 'Prev ' . $prev.'and Current: ' . $data[1] . '<br/>';  $prev = $data[1];
 }
 print 'Previous is not the same<br/>';
 print 'Prev ' . $prev.'and Current: ' . $data[1];
 $prev = $data[1];  
    }
}
fclose($handle);

Comment: I added the output I get. It's different from yours. If you are using the exact same code, you might want to look into the character set your OS and/or PHP version is using.

Comment: BTW if you don't get into the inner loop it looks like your PHP cannot find the file.